# NAS running trueNAS core with direct link to PC

Tags: networking, ethernet, nas

I have a nas running trueNAS core and a pc running windows. My goal is to connect these two together with 2.5 gigabit ethernet. My idea was to use 1 gigabit ethernet from both devices to a switch that connects to the rest of the network and 2.5 gigabit ethernet between the two.

My idea being that I can use the NAS from any device in the network with the lower speed as they do not require the full bandwidth, while my main pc has a faster connection for large file transfers.

I don’t just want to put a 2.5 gigabit switch between the two and the rest of the network because the switches are still rather expensive. While the pcie cards are already pretty affordable.

Would this setup be possible? And if yes, how do I define the ips of the pcs for the interlink?

Comment: So you want to use a direct network connection between the storage device and the PC, and then another network connection for the broader network. Yes, it's possible. So, what have you tried? What research have you done? This is pretty much possible, AFAIK.